# Proof of Uniqueness of Heat Equation using Maximum Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I came across the proof of uniqueness of heat equation solution.
Theorem: Let $u_1(x), u_2(x)$ be two solutions of the following:
$$u_t= \alpha u_{xx},  0<x<L,  t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=g(t),  u(L,t)=h(t)$$
$$u(x,0) = f(x)$$
where $f(x),g(t),h(t)$ are given functions. Then $u_1(x,t)=u_2(x,t)$ for all $0 \leq x \leq L, t>0$.

Proof:  Set $w(x,t)=u_1(x,t) - u_2(x,t)$. Then $w$ satisfies
$$w_t= \alpha w_{xx},  0<x<L,  t>0$$
$$w(0,t)=0,  w(L,t)=0$$
$$w(x,0) = 0$$
Then, I do not understand the following part:
By the maximum principle, we must have
$$w(x,t) \leq 0$$

How does the maximum principle implies $w(x,t) \leq 0$ ?
Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, what *is* the maximum principle for the heat equation, to begin with? Once you make that clear, your question will answer itself.

Comment: @HansLundmark, thank you for your reply. The maximum principle states: Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution of $u_t=\alpha u_{xx},  0 \leq x \leq L,  0 < t \leq T$ which is continuous in the closed region R : $0 \leq x \leq L,  0 \leq t \leq T$. The maximum and minimum values of $u(x,t)$ are assumed on the initial line $t=0$, or at the points on the boundary $x=0$ and $x=L$.  



So, does it implies $sup (w) = 0 $ (from the boundary conditions $w(0,t)=0,w(L,t)=0$ and initial condition $w(x,0) = 0$ )  ? And, hence, $w(x,t)$ must be $ \leq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, it's as simple as that!